# Replace specific characters in an alphabet

Tags: fonts, alphabet

\I want to replace how specific characters in an alphabet are rendered. For example, when I write`\bm{\mu}`, I want it to compile as `\boldsymbol{\upmu}`. Also possible, to define a new "sub-alphabet" such as `\up{...}` which will compile `\bm{\up{\mu}}` as  `\boldsymbol{\upmu}`.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: You can use \let\mu=\upmu, provided \upmu does not use \mu in its definition.

Comment: You could implement `\up{\mu}` using `\ifx\mu#1\relax` \upmu\fi.  Slow and ugly

Comment: John, I want to use `\umpu` and `\mu` in the same text so that's not going to work. For the second comment, I'll check it out.